# Conclusion of a theorem involving the minimal polynomial and eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Theorem

[image]

The lecturer then states that the conclusion of this theorem means that "there is a non-zero $v \in \mathbb{V}_{b_j}(\lambda_j) \backslash V_{b_j - 1} (\lambda_j)$" however I don't see how this theorem concludes that, could someone show me this step please

Comment: You have two sets that you have shown are not equal. Depending on your conventions, either both contain zero or neither contain zero. So their set difference contains a nonzero vector.

Comment: What do you mean set difference? I thought $V \backslash W$ means $V$ without the elements of $W$

Comment: That is what set difference means.